# PostgreSQL does not find function

Tags: python, json, postgresql, casting, postgrest

I have defined a function in my PostgreSQL 10.18 database like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_event(event json)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "eventlog" VALUES(event::json->'event_type',
                                  event::json->'message',
                                  event::json->'user',
                                  now());
END
$BODY$;
```

I can call it successfully from pgAdmin like this:

```
select log_event('{"event_type": "foo", "message": "bar", "user": "foobar"}'::json);
```

But when I try to call it from my Python code, that talks to the database via the PostGREST API:

```
event = {
  "event": {
    "event_type": "foo",
    "message": "bar",
    "user": "foobar"
  }
}

requests.post('https://server/rpc/log_event', json=event)
```

It fails with:

```
{"hint":"No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
"details":null,
"code":"42883",
"message":"function public.log_event(event => text) does not exist"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the function parameter as type `json`. Your function call from pgAdmin passes type `json` - you have an explicit cast there (`::json`).

It would also work with an untyped string literal.

But your call from Python passes type `text`, and that's where Postgres bails out. There is no implicit cast registered for  `text` --> `json`. Pass type `json` or an untyped string literal instead.

(Alternatively, create a function taking `text` instead, and use an explicit cast (once) inside the function, but that's an inferior solution.)

[The PostgREST manual:](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#calling-functions-with-a-single-json-parameter)

> You can also call a function that takes **a single parameter of type
> JSON** by sending the header **`Prefer: params=single-object`** with your
> request. That way the JSON request body will be used as the single
> argument.

Bold emphasis mine.

Also, to match your function, there is no outer "event" key in the passed JSON object:

```json
event = {
    "event_type": "foo",
    "message": "bar",
    "user": "foobar"
}
```

#### Cleaner function

Aside, your function cleaned up:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_event(event json)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO public.eventlog    -- (a, b, c, d) -- ①
   VALUES (event -> 'event_type'  -- ②
         , event -> 'message'     -- ? ③
         , event -> 'user'
         , now());
END
$func$;
```

① Better provide an explicit target column list (with actual target column names). Else, later schema changes may silently break your code.

② Drop the added cast, `event` is already type `json`.

③ You want to store `json` values? I suspect you really want `event ->> 'message'` to get `text` instead. With the [->> operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE).

Comment: Thanks! But: how to I do that: "But your call from Python passes type text, and that's where Postgres bails out. There is no implicit cast registered for text --> json. Pass type json or an untyped string literal instead." ?

Comment: @Halmackenreuter: I added pointers above.